# Animating scroll in UICollectionView - iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, ios10

I am programatically scrolling my collection view. It works perfectly on every iOS version except for iOS 10. The collection view scrolls without animation, it just snaps into place.

**Is this a bug or I should be doing something differently in iOS 10?**

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *visibleItems = [collectionViewReference indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *previousItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item - 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
[collectionViewReference scrollToItemAtIndexPath:previousItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm seeing some weird behaviour with my collectionview on iOS 10. Not the same thing, but it's possible some bugs were introduced with the collection views.

Comment: I have the same problem. Everything is ok when i call scrollToItemAtIndexPath with animates:NO but i have the problem when animated: YES

Comment: Try collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false. I have another performance issue on 10 and this helped. Looks like it takes some main thread execution time from other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

may I repeat, but it really helped me. In setting up my UIViewCollection i set:
 `prefetchingEnabled = NO`
And this bug was not repeated and scrollItemAtIndexPath with animation works correct.